# Set Hostname/IP before running command in C#

Tags: c#

I have a button that when clicked is running a CMD prompt:

```
    private void PingCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText); 
    }
```

What I'd like to happen is before the command prompt is opened I'd like a box to appear where I can specify the Hostname/IP that is to be ping'd - is this possible and if so how would I do this?

OR if possible the Hostname/IP address to be set for multiple buttons; ie. ping, map home drive and so on!

Thanks

Comment: Is it Windows or Web Forms? Create 2 textboxes and, at `PingCommand_Click`, retrieve their values and concatenate to `strCmdText`

Comment: Windows - Would it be possible to give me an example section of code, I'm new to C# and programming.

Comment: Could you kindly provide any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Hi Andre, I have done that now!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see that. I've provided the basic code that you asked for, trying to teach you how things work, and you hadn't given a single vote up.

Comment: I can't Vote Up as it requires 15 reputation points and I only have 3! I appreciate your answer however

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following code, it will run the ping command and return the result to the result variable. You need to change the path to ping.exe.

```
var fileName = "C:\\path-to\\ping.exe";
var arguments = txtHostname.Text;

var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName ,  arguments);
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
using (var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo)) {
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8)){
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) 
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this if I wanted to output the data to a listbox how would I do this?

Comment: Edited to add result lines to listbox

Comment: That's great thanks, is there any reason it's only pinging once?

Comment: Fixed, change the while statement please.

Answer (score 2):

Although starting a commandline tool is possible I would suggest using the `Ping class` available in .Net Framework 4.0 ([Ping Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx))

This is a modification of an example at MSDN

```
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using System.Diagnostics; // for demo purposes only

    private void PingCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
        int timeout = 120;
        string ipOrHost = "80.108.20.100"; // or access your textbox
        //string ipOrHost = txtIP.Text;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (ipOrHost, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Address: " + reply.Address.ToString ());
            Debug.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: " + reply.RoundtripTime);
            Debug.WriteLine ("Time to live: " + reply.Options.Ttl);
            Debug.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: " + reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Debug.WriteLine ("Buffer size: " + reply.Buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

In case you really need to start any commandLine tool you may have a look at `Process` and `ProcessInfo` classes (example codes at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible. You should prompt the user with a dialog window where they can enter the IP address and then pass this IP address to the `Process.Start()` method using a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class instance that specifies the [command-line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) to pass to the process.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to get the IP from a text box then do `strCmdText = "ping " + MyTextBox.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

Your **view** (*.aspx) would be something like

```
...
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Hostname/IP to ping: <asp:TextBox ID="destination" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="ping" runat="server" Text="Ping it!" onclick="ping_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
...
```

and your **codebehind** (*.aspx.cs)

```
    ...
    protected void ping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.destination.Text))
        {
            string strCmdText = string.Concat("ping ", this.destination.Text.Trim());
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
            //and so on...
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I can't Vote Up as it requires 15 reputation points and I only have 3! I appreciate your answer however.